# ReactJs page renders fine when using .map of objects but if use index of array runs on first save but crashes on reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing, axios, array.prototype.map

I am creating a flashcard app, already have a page where I use .map() to render all items. Now I created another page so I can individually show one card at a time, so instead of using .map I used items[x] so I can increment by one with a onClick button. When I first save the file the live update renders fine as predicted, yet if I reload the page it crashes saying that it cannot read the word property of undefined. Now after doing some debugging I found that If I console log the array at first it shows up as zero/0 then prints out again with the info, even though I call the useSelector function to gather the info from the state before trying to access the data. Now this happens no matter if I use the .map() function but for some reason the .map() function does not crash and render fine as expected.

```
import React from "react";
import FlippableFlashcard from "../FlippableFlashcards/FlippableCard/FlippableCard.jsx";
import { Button, Container, Box } from "@mui/material";
import ArrowRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowRight";
import ArrowLeftIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowLeft";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import useStyles from "./styles.js";

const Practice = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const items = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

  const handleAdd = () => {};

  return (
    <>
      <Container className={classes.centerDiv}>
        <FlippableFlashcard item={console.log(items[0])} />
        {/*//This fails, but this does not <FlippableFlashcard item={items.map((item) => console.log(item))} />*/}
      </Container>
      <Box textAlign="center" className={classes.ButtonBar}>
        <Button onClick={handleAdd}>
          <ArrowLeftIcon />
        </Button>
        <Button>
          <ArrowRightIcon />
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default Practice;
```

specifically this `<FlippableFlashcard item={console.log(items[0])} />`

Error:

```
FlippableCard.jsx:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'word')
```

So I know it is because of that first console log being 0/null/undefined. Tried doing `{ items && items[0] }` as I saw some saying this would work but did not.

Comment: I think you need to add a check before using the items array.
Add a check for if the items array has any value, then only access the value.
Something like this:
<FlippableFlashcard item={items?.length ? console.log(items[0]) : ''} />

Comment: Thx, the most simple method was the right one, I was thinking about it but was confused that at first it would not render on the first try.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Akshay Mathur, I just simply did, works great, basically checks if data exists if not then simply console logs fetching, on the second auto reload it will render.

```
{items.length ? (
          <FlippableFlashcard item={items[x]} key={items[x]._id} />
        ) : (
          console.log("fetching data")
        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
{items.length > 0 && items.map((item,index)=>(<FlippableFlashcard item={item} key={index} />)}
```